# How to Delete the Existing data based on Where clause condition using Merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have written a merge Statement where i am facing trouble to delete the data basing on Where Clause Condition.
Let me explain my scenario Clearly

1. For example i have inserted Data from Source to Target based on Date Key Condition.Take an Instance 10 Records Inserted.
2. For example some changes in the records and it has been updated through the Merge Statement .
3. For the Same Date key based on Conditions now three records has came and need to be inserted and rest should be deleted for that Date Key.

How i need to proceed on this before 10 records are not getting deleted and new records adding for that one

My Example Code :

```
 DELETE FROM #Table1
CREATE  TABLE #Table1  
(ID INT ,Name VARCHAR(30),DATEKEY INT)
INSERT INTO #Table1 (ID,Name,DATEKEY)VALUES (1,'Mohan',20131231)
INSERT INTO #Table1 (ID,Name,DATEKEY)VALUES (2,'Raj',20131231)
INSERT INTO #Table1 (ID,Name,DATEKEY)VALUES (3,'Majjaa',20131231)
INSERT INTO #Table1 (ID,Name,DATEKEY)VALUES (4,'Majjaa',20131231)

CREATE TABLE  #Table2  
(ID INT ,Name VARCHAR(30),DATEKEY INT)

DECLARE @i_DateKey INT
SET @i_DateKey = '20131231'
    MERGE #Table2 AS T
    USING (
        SELECT pdp.ID
            ,pdp.Name
            ,pdp.DATEKEY
        FROM  #Table1 AS pdp

        WHERE (
                pdp.DateKey = @i_DateKey
                OR @i_DateKey IS NULL
                )
        ) AS S
        ON T.ID = S.ID
            AND T.DateKey = S.DateKey
            AND T.NAME = S.NAME
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE
            SET T.NAME = S.NAME
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            INSERT
            VALUES (
                S.ID
                ,S.Name
                ,S.DateKey
                )

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
     THEN
      DELETE ;
```

Now the target table will be loaded with Rows now if i send the another row for Same Date key then it need to be deleted all the 4 rows and reload the new Row if the new row is same then need to update

Comment: your code appear to be ok.where is the problem ?just change when not matched by Target then insert when not matched by Source then delete.explain the real problem

Comment: yeah code wise it is okay basing on the requirement it is not working

Comment: can you explain with sample data then ?

Comment: Okay then i will re-edit my question

Comment: why don't you try old classic way,if exists(select ........where datakey)
begin delete...... end

Comment: main problem i see is how to differentiate between update/delete ?use extra variable like @flag=1 then update else delete

Comment: already i used this statement in my delete  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Table1 tt WHERE tt.ID = T.ID  )
  THEN
   DELETE ;

Comment: can you just post me sample example or solution i tried in so many ways

Comment: your requirement is not clear.you have to differentiate between update and delete.in fact you don't require update here instead make it delete and remove the last delete.Or if you need update then no need of delete.#Point2 "For example some changes in the records..is not clear.what parameter is pass to proc.how data arrive in #table1.isn't there any filter in first place.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is one big mistake,

```
ON T.ID = S.ID  --i am not sure about this
            AND T.DateKey = S.DateKey
            AND T.NAME = S.NAME -- remove this because this when matched then update will do what ?
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE
            SET T.NAME = S.NAME
```